# Facebook single-sign-on (SSO) sometimes doesn't work

Tags: android, facebook

I frequently get complaints from customers that they can't click the Allow button on the SSO screen of my app, that's based on the Facebook SDK.  They say that it simply does not respond to clicks.

I have never been able to reproduce this problem. But it occasionally does have various errors when you do press the button, but trying a couple of times always ends up working.

Has anyone else encountered this issue? If I can't find a solution, I'm just going to have to permanently disable SSO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a similar problem that I had. It was solved by *not* calling the Facebook app by default when going to authorize. To do so, simply add `Facebook.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH` to the `authorize` parameters. A similar post with this answer [can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10815813/android-facebook-authorization-can-not-login-when-official-facebook-app-instal/10816381#10816381).

I hope it helps =]

Comment: Yeah, I eventually did something similar. I present the user with two different buttons Quick Login (for SSO) and Dialog Login.