# Facebook login is not working from my application in Samsung Galaxy

Tags: android, facebook

I did Facebook integration in my application. The login screen is not loading without SSO and with SSO its not getting the Facebook user's details from default Facebook app in Samsung Galaxy.

The same code I run on HTC its working fine.
I never faced this kind of problem before. I do not know why it does this.

I am getting following response:

```
The server failed to communicate. Try again later.
```

Has anybody faced the same problem?

Comment: In your Samsung galaxy and HTC device the default facebook app is installed or not?

Comment: try below stack overflow's answer link for that, may be it will help you. [How to disable facebook native app for user login](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11860119/how-to-disable-facebook-native-app-for-user-login/11860731#11860731)

Comment: I tried this but still getting white screen with loading

Comment: yes if it wrong it won't work on HTC also?

Comment: I am having exactly the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: its not working some Samsung devices.I do not know exact problem.But it working in remain.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are submitting request to wrong url or there is mistake in the content you are sending.