# Android facebook login read permission

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login

In my android app i am using facebook login for authentication purpose. Everything goes fine till facebook app was not available in my device. After installing facebook app, i opened my app and goes for facebook login, automatically my app authenticates using my facebook app credentials. It doesn't ask for any permission to the users. Is their any possibilities for asking permission before authenticates.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this link you will get the solution

[How to disable facebook native app for user login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11860119/how-to-disable-facebook-native-app-for-user-login)

I am sure you are not specifying Facebook native login dialog in your code