# Login failed. Action canceled. Facebook sandbox

Tags: android, facebook

I set my Facebook app as a sandbox. I login in Hackbook demo. After athentication, it shows a loading dialog then close right after that. There is no any log. What's wrong with my it? How to fix?

Comment: Hi Emerald, me also working with same hackbook demo..It's working fine for me.. See this link: http://lokeshatandroid.blogspot.in/2012/07/facebookintegration-into-android.html

Comment: Do you use sandbox mode?

Comment: No.., dont know about that sandbox mode.. may I know what was that??

Comment: @Emerald214 Please See my answer and if answer is helping you then please accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please update below code of your Login Button Click listener, it will solve your problem.

```
facebook.authorize(mActivity, mPermissions, Facebook.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH,
            new LoginDialogListener());
```

And see below link for more information.

[Facebook Login Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10815813/android-facebook-authorization-can-not-login-when-official-facebook-app-instal/10816381#10816381)