# Android-facebookSDK With SSO

Tags: android

I am using android facebooksdk with sso for facebook access. It works if the device has facebook app installed. And it is not recognizing whether user is logged in facebook via the default browser. Is there any way to make sso work for browsers

Answer (score 1):

The reason android facebooksdk is working with the app, cause the facebook app is integrated to the OS, which helps in detecting the credentials, but in the browser it is not show.

Comment: so in android  is it not possible to make sso work with browser?

Comment: its not only in Android, may be in iOS also, its not possible till you have facebook integrated to the OS itself.

Answer (score 0):

Please Update below code of your application, it will solve your problem.

```
public void loginAndPostToWall() {
    facebook.authorize(this, PERMISSIONS, Facebook.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH,
            new LoginDialogListener());
}
```

And see below Stack Overflow link for more information.

[Facebook Authorization can't login when Official Facebook Application Installed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10816381/1466188)