# App misconfigured - Could not log in to Facebook when official Facebook app is installed

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I checked the Hackbook code in **Facebook SDK 3.0** - samples and I get the error as if the app is misconfigured, when the official Facebook app is installed. If I delete the official installed Facebook app it works fine.

Similarly I have this error for my app too. I have checked the keyhashes in the Facebook app dashboard.

[image]

I went through Stack Overflow *[Android Facebook authorization - can not log in when official Facebook app is installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10815813/android-facebook-authorization-can-not-login-when-official-facebook-app-instal)*, but it took me to the `webdialog`, but I want to use as native app and don't want to use `WebDialog`.

I went through https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/ and configured all the details in the Facebook App Dashboard.

I have been searching for more than a week and I could not get any solution. I don't know where I am going wrong. Any related answers are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to upload your app on Google Play or if there is the default Facebook App is installed in your phone, then you need a different `KeyHash`. Because, when you developed your Facebook app you have registered your Facebook app with a key hash which is created by using the default `debug.keystore`.

So, now you need a different `KeyStore` to generate the different KeyHash. You need a signed `KeyStore`, which you get by the help of [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IYhJp-jqJyM). After generating a new keystore, generate a key hash and register your Facebook app with this new key hash. This should work.

**EDITED:**

You should check your .apk key hash to be sure you have registered with this key hash. You should check out these: *[Key hash for Android-Facebook app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388992/key-hash-for-android-facebook-app#14332237)* and *[App is misconfigured for Facebook login - not returning the logcat, after setting ENABLE_LOG to true in util.java](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/13966906/app-is-misconfigured-for-facebook-login-not-returning-the-logcat-after-setti#13978762)*.

Comment: are u intalling the specific .apk which generated during the procedure to create the new key hash ?

Comment: yes , i install the same .apk which was signed using the .keystore file with which i took the hash key .

Comment: why u r not interested to use webdialog login ?

Answer (score 0):

you need to get different Hash Key and paste in facebook developer app configuration profile then try to login..

Comment: different Hash key ? - i am getting the key of my app's keystore file only . sorry i could not get you